# Occasional inline HTML compilation with Slim-Lang?

Tags: html, inline, slim-lang

I'm trying slim-lang.

```
td something
```

is compiled as :

```
<td>
    something
</td>
```

I'd like it to be compiled like this :

```
<td>something</td>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: why not just minify the html after it has been compiled? With a tool like [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) this can easily be done...

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled the `--pretty` flag. Turn it off and it will render as you wish:

```
% slimrb -s <<< "td something"
<td>something</td>

% slimrb -s --pretty <<< "td something"
<td>
   something
</td>
```